# Docker Error starting container interactively

Tags: docker

I use the EC2 amazone system I start the ubuntu server on it I put doker in doker I create the image with such text

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install apache2

RUN echo 'Hello aws!' > /var/www/html/index.html


CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D","FOREGROUND"]
EXPOSE 80
```

starting to build `docker build -t yar:v1 .`
and then run interactively `docker run -it -p 7777:80 yar:v1` shows an error:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

Comment: Does it serve HTTP requests?  Beyond that warning message, what's going wrong?

Comment: what did you want to happen? when you go to `http://localhost:7777` do get a reply?

Comment: Unable to access site

Comment: and why don't you use [`httpd`](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd) image? its the official apache HTTP docker image

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Apache to define the `ServerName` to get rid of this warning message, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/apache-error-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-n) for more detail.
For example by adding the following line in your `Dockerfile`.

```
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Then you can simply run (it has not to be run interactively but more as a daemon `-d`).

```sh
docker run -d -p 7777:80
curl localhost:7777                         
# Hello aws!
```

However I guess it is for test purposes, because you should use directly an apache [`httpd` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd) instead for a lot of reasons (init script, root user, etc).

```
FROM httpd

RUN echo 'Hello aws!' > /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html
```

Comment: The browser says Unable to access the site

Comment: @Ярослав I don't know where you run the container but if you do it from an EC2 and if you try to access it from your browser, you need to perform network settings on your VPC in order to open the port. This is beyond the scope of this answer.